# "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary" in universal windows project

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working on a UWP game as a school project and I recently ran into this error stating "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary". I cannot run the project,build or rebuild it. I've been looking for a solution for days, but no luck. I'm currently moving the code to a different project, but i'd like to fix the issue in my current project.

Comment: This issue sounds like you have a reference that implements this type. I'd suggest you check the code part by part when you moving the code to the new project to find out which part of the code causes the issue.

Comment: I think you should manually delete the bin and obj folder from the project directory while vs is closed and reopen the project and hit clear all and then rebuild all some time this solves my same problem. somehow the vs reference to the other directory the lastly compiled to  OBJ folder but not correct or changed by any means